# How to update and return state in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my componentwillmount method, i need to init the state of the component and i want to use update&return new state instead of doing setState multiple time

My code now is kind of

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState(
        data1: doSomeCalculationAndReturnData1
    );
    //do other processX
    this.setState(
        data2: doSomeCalculationAndReturnData2
    );
    //do other processY
}
```

I would like to do it like this, but it is not working when i tried this second approach, please advise me

```
componentWillMount() {
    //do other processX
    //do other processY
    return {
        ...state,
        data1: doSomeCalculationAndReturnData1
        data2: doSomeCalculationAndReturnData2
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What's "not working"?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, nothing does anything with the return value of `componentWillMount`...? (Also note that that method is going away in v17...)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with return statement in willMount?

Answer (score 1):

In latest React version (16.5.1) componentWillMount method marked as deprecated. 
"Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead for initializing state" - quote from official docs.

However, return value in componentWillMount doesn't affect any changes and you should use setState with argument contains two properties data1 and data2.

```
setState({
    data1: doSomeCalculationAndReturnData1,
    data2: doSomeCalculationAndReturnData2
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do it like this

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    this.setState({
        data1: do_some_calculation_and_return_data_1,
        data2: do_some_calculation_and_return_data_2
    })
}
```

or you could do it in the `constructor` method

Answer (score 0):

You can set state in following manner. Also you don't want to spread existing state because it is useless operation in this case.

```
componentWillMount() {
    const data1 = computedData1;
    const data2  = computedData2;
    this.setState({data1, data2});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do it at the `constructor` of component. You can initialize state there without call `setState`.

```jsx
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  //do other processX
  //do other processY

  this.state = {
    data1: doSomeCalculationAndReturnData1,
    data2: doSomeCalculationAndReturnData2
  };
}
```